# Failed to download file with retrofit2

Tags: retrofit, okhttp

File size about 68M

```
public interface ServiceApi {
    @GET("QQ_7.9.16621.0_setup.1448418488.exe")
    @Streaming
    Call<ResponseBody> getFile();

    @GET("QQ_7.9.16621.0_setup.1448418488.exe")
    @Streaming
    Observable<Response<ResponseBody>> getFileRx();
}

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
                .Builder()
                .baseUrl(RestConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(new OkHttpClient())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

my gradle configuration

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:adapter-rxjava:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'

compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.16'
```

when i use

serviceApi.getFile().enqueue(new Callback() {.....}

it is running well;

but when i use

```
serviceApi.getFileRx()
                   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {....}
```

it throws an exception,and fails.

Error Log:

```
11-30 20:30:54.470 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err: java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:137)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
11-30 20:30:54.473 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:139)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:418)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:50)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.ForwardingSource.read(ForwardingSource.java:35)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at retrofit.OkHttpCall$ExceptionCatchingRequestBody$1.read(OkHttpCall.java:220)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at stdying.retrofitdemo.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:160)
11-30 20:30:54.477 28998-29093/stdying.retrofitdemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**I use mistake?**

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue ?